# How to prohibit users from installing specific software in windows system in an AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, domain-controller

I've different OUs for different Departments. For Example *Mechanical OU* and *Programmers OU*. I don't want to block the users entirely from installing and Uninstalling software. For example users of mechanical OU should be able to install CAD software(such as AutoCAD, SolidWorks) Programmers shouldn't be able to install those softwares on their system. Programmers should only be able to install and uninstall software that they need and vice versa. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not just deploy everything each person needs up-front?  Saves everyone time and hassle.

Comment: if something goes wrong with the installed software. I want the user to be able to reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at using Applocker policies deployed from AD GPO. It's the technology progression of Software Restriction Policies and has some good features for application whitelisting/blacklisting. Check here for the MS guide on how to configure it:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/maintain-applocker-policies#bkmk-applkr-use-gp

The info says it applies to Windows 10 but Applocker policies can be deployed to Windows 7 & up. Hope that helps.

Cheers

Joe

Answer (score 2):

Use Software Restriction Policies in GPO. Set default Security Level to Unrestricted. Under Additional Rules set a path rule using a wildcard file path (eg. *autocad* or *solidworks*) and set the individual security level to Disallowed.